# Element equals its index time limit not being passed

Tags: python-3.x

```
def index_equals_value(arr):


    for num in enumerate(arr):
        if num[0] == num[1]:
            return num[0]
    return -1
```

I finished this programming challenge where I have to find which first number matches its index and if it does return the first index that the number is in. I exceeded the time limit of 1.500 seconds and I feel I can use a list comprehension here or a one-liner so it would be faster but I am struggling to learn the concept right now. If anyone has any good videos or advice about line comprehension or one-liners I can use to lessen the O time that would be great! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try BinarySearch if your arr is sorted. It's a time complexity of o(log n ).

I also found a GeeksForGeeks with that problem.(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-fixed-point-in-a-given-array/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Here's a good source of knowledge https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/